# Bad command output in MacVim

Tags: django, django-admin, macvim

I'm going through the Django tutorial http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/#activating-models, which outputs colorized SQL snippets via `python manage.py sql polls`. I'm working with MacVim and it seems that it does not understand the output properly. See screenshot.

[image: MacVim bad command output]

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the terminal emulator supplied by MacVim isn't a fully-functional terminal (i.e. one capable of supporting ANSI escape codes), but it looks like it's claiming to be. You might try [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) vimscript which claims to be able to colourize files with ANSI escape codes.