# VIM Unix commands printed in color

Tags: vim, macvim, ansi-escape

I'm using MacVim and I would like to have `!` commands printed in color. For example:

In bash, the following echo statement prints Hello World in green (as expected):

```
$ echo -e "\033[32m Hello World" 
 Hello World
```

However, in VIM the output is not color, and the escape codes are printed:

```
:!echo -e "\033[32m Hello World" 
 [32m Hello World
```

How can one have VIM (and MacVim build 57 in particular) print the output of `!` commands and honour ANSI color escapes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bad command output in MacVim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765378/bad-command-output-in-macvim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. But you can suspend the editor and drop to a shell relatively quickly;

Or you can use **[`Ansi Filter`](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/ansifilter.html)** to remove the escape sequences so you will at least not see a mess.

Answer (score 2):

this one:

```
:!echo $(tput setaf 1)Hello world$(tput sgr0)
```

will print `Hello world` in color.

Don't use escape sequences, but named tput entries. (all times, not only in this example). read:
man teminfo; man infocmp; man tput - for more information.

based on comments I found this question very interesting.

Still searching for the better solution, but for now find this one - http://code.google.com/p/conque/ .
Allow run colored commands inside MacVim's buffer.

Comment: While interesting, I don't expect this answers the question. I think the 'echo' with ANSI escapes was just a minimal example of what he means. Usually, what really transpires is a `git diff` with color enabled, or `make`,`diff`,`gcc` being symlinked to color{make,diff,gcc} etc

Comment: @sehe, @jm666: Yes, the ANSI is a minimal example, though this is helpful. In any case, though, when I tried the example in MacVim it didn't print in color.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this would help, but running my RSpec tests inside vim gives me colored output using the `--color` option. I use the following command to run the current spec file inline:

`:map ,t :w\|:!rspec --color %<cr>`

Answer (score 1):

If you run macvim in console mode (vim, not mvim) all :! commands are redirected to the shell and executed there. They take the whole window instead of 1/3 of it, and they use whatever theme your console happens to have.

But you get ansicolors.

Comment: If you're running in console mode it's probably better to simply suspend the process (ctrl + z), execute the command and then bring vim's process back (run `fg`).

Answer (score 0):

Your question (and its pop up done by @avocade) addressed the issue I have with some printing in my aurum plugin thus I’ve wrote (started to write, but the most significant piece of functionality is already here) the [ansi_esc_echo](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/ansi_esc_echo) plugin. To use it in your one you must install it, install [frawor](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/frawor) and do

```
execute frawor#Setup('0.0', {'autoload/ansi_esc_echo': '0.0'})
call s:_r.ansi_esc.echo("\e[33mabc")
```

. Currently it deals only (speaking exclusively about special characters or sequences) with carriage return, backspace (untested), tab, newline, and CSI colors.